# how to update firestore database value correctly

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, sharedpreferences

I am working to build basic shopping functions in my Flutter app.  I'm new to coding and Flutter.  When the user clicks the PlaceOrderPageContainer (button) to confirm check out the addOrderDetails() method is called which then updates the Firebase database. Everything is updating in Firestore Database correctly other than the Total Amount which is being added as zero regardless of the total amount in the shopping cart.  I'm not getting any errors in the console but it's obvious my code isn't written correctly.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.  I can add any additional code if that will be helpful.

```
    class ShoppingCartPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ShoppingCartPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ShoppingCartPageState createState() => _ShoppingCartPageState();
}

class _ShoppingCartPageState extends State<ShoppingCartPage> {
  late double totalAmount;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    totalAmount = 0;
    Provider.of<TotalAmountProvider>(
      context,
      listen: false,
    ).display(0);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer2<TotalAmountProvider, CartItemCounterProvider>(
      builder: (context, amountProvider, cartProvider, c) {
        return SafeArea(
          child: Scaffold(
            appBar: const ShoppingCartAppBar(),
            floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
              onPressed: () {
                if (ShoppingApp.sharedPreferences
                        .getStringList(
                          ShoppingApp.userCartList,
                        )
                        ?.length ==
                    1) {
                  Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: ToastString.cartEmpty);
                } else {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => AddressPage(
                        totalAmount: totalAmount,
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                }
              },
              icon: const Icon(
                Icons.navigate_next,
              ),
              label: Text(
                ButtonString.checkOut.toUpperCase(),
              ),
            ),
            body: CustomScrollView(
              slivers: [
                SliverToBoxAdapter(
                  child:
                      Consumer2<TotalAmountProvider, CartItemCounterProvider>(
                    builder: (context, amountProvider, cartProvider, c) {
                      return Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Center(
                          child: cartProvider.count == 0
                              ? Container()
                              : Text(
                                  'Total Price: \$${amountProvider.totalAmount.toString()}',
                                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6,
                                ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                    stream: ShoppingApp.firestore
                        .collection('items')
                        .where('shortInfo',
                            whereIn: ShoppingApp.sharedPreferences
                                .getStringList(ShoppingApp.userCartList))
                        .snapshots(),
                    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                      return !snapshot.hasData
                          ? const AdaptiveCircularProgressSliver()
                          : snapshot.data.docs.isEmpty
                              ? const EmptyShoppingCartContainer()
                              : SliverList(
                                  delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                                    (context, index) {
                                      ItemModel model = ItemModel.fromJson(
                                        snapshot.data.docs[index].data(),
                                      );
                                      if (index == 0) {
                                        totalAmount = 0;
                                        // totalAmount = model.price! + totalAmount;
                                      } else {
                                        totalAmount =
                                            model.price! + totalAmount;
                                      }
                                      if (snapshot.data?.docs.length - 1 ==
                                          index) {
                                        WidgetsBinding.instance!
                                            .addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
                                          Provider.of<TotalAmountProvider>(
                                                  context,
                                                  listen: false)
                                              .display(totalAmount);
                                        });
                                      }
                                      return sourceInfo(
                                        model,
                                        context,
                                        removeCartFunction: () =>
                                            removeItemFromUserCart(
                                          model.shortInfo as String,
                                        ),
                                      );
                                    },
                                    childCount: snapshot.hasData
                                        ? snapshot.data?.docs.length
                                        : 0,
                                  ),
                                );
                    }),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Future<void> removeItemFromUserCart(
    String shortInfoAsID,
  ) async {
    List<String>? tempCartList = ShoppingApp.sharedPreferences.getStringList(
      ShoppingApp.userCartList,
    );
    tempCartList?.remove(shortInfoAsID);

    await ShoppingApp.firestore
        .collection(ShoppingApp.collectionUser)
        .doc(ShoppingApp.sharedPreferences.getString(
          ShoppingApp.userUID,
        ))
        .update({
      ShoppingApp.userCartList: tempCartList,
    }).then((value) {
      Fluttertoast.showToast(
        msg: ToastString.removeFromCart,
      );
      ShoppingApp.sharedPreferences.setStringList(
        ShoppingApp.userCartList,
        tempCartList as List<String>,
      );

      Provider.of<CartItemCounterProvider>(
        context,
        listen: false,
      ).displayResult();

      totalAmount = 0;
    });
  }
}

class AddressPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const AddressPage({
    Key? key,
    required this.totalAmount,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final double totalAmount;

  @override
  _AddressPageState createState() => _AddressPageState();
}

class _AddressPageState extends State<AddressPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: AdaptiveLayoutScaffold(
        appBar: const AddressPageAppBar(),
        floatingActionButton: const AddNewAddressFAB(),
        landscapeBodyWidget: Container(),
        portraitBodyWidget: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            const AddressPageHeadline(
              headlineText: ShoppingPageString.selectAddress,
            ),
            Consumer<AddressChangerProvider>(builder: (
              context,
              address,
              c,
            ) {
              return Flexible(
                child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                    stream: ShoppingApp.firestore
                        .collection(ShoppingApp.collectionUser)
                        .doc(ShoppingApp.sharedPreferences
                            .getString(ShoppingApp.userUID))
                        .collection(ShoppingApp.subCollectionAddress)
                        .snapshots(),
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      return !snapshot.hasData
                          ? const AdaptiveCircularProgressCenter()
                          : snapshot.data!.docs.isEmpty
                              ? const EmptyShippingAddressContainer()
                              : ListView.builder(
                                  itemCount: snapshot.data?.docs.length,
                                  shrinkWrap: true,
                                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                    return AddressCard(
                                      addressID: snapshot.data?.docs[index].id
                                          as String,
                                      currentIndex: address.count,
                                      model: AddressModel.fromJson(
                                        snapshot.data?.docs[index].data()
                                            as Map<String, dynamic>,
                                      ),
                                      totalAmount: widget.totalAmount,
                                      value: index,
                                    );
                                  },
                                );
                    }),
              );
            }),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AddressCard extends StatefulWidget {

  const AddressCard({
    Key? key,
    required this.addressID,
    required this.currentIndex,
    required this.model,
    required this.totalAmount,
    required this.value,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String addressID;
  final int currentIndex;
  final AddressModel model;
  final double totalAmount;
  final int value;

  @override
  _AddressCardState createState() => _AddressCardState();
}

class _AddressCardState extends State<AddressCard> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AddressCardContainer(
      onTap: () {
        Provider.of<AddressChangerProvider>(
          context,
          listen: false,
        ).displayResult(widget.value);
      },
      addressCardColumn: AddressCardColumn(
        children: [
          Row(
            children: [
              AddressCardRadioButton(
                groupValue: widget.currentIndex,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  Provider.of<AddressChangerProvider>(
                    context,
                    listen: false,
                  ).displayResult(
                    value as int,
                  );
                },
                value: widget.value,
              ),
              AddressCardContent(
                city: widget.model.city as String,
                fullName: widget.model.name as String,
                phoneNumber: widget.model.phoneNumber as String,
                postalCode: widget.model.postalCode as String,
                state: widget.model.state as String,
                streetAddress: widget.model.streetAddress as String,
              ),
            ],
          ),
          widget.value == Provider.of<AddressChangerProvider>(context).count
              ? ShippingAddressProceedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (
                          context,
                        ) =>
                            PlaceOrderPaymentPage(
                          addressID: widget.addressID,
                          totalAmount: widget.totalAmount,
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                )
              : Container(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PlaceOrderPaymentPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const PlaceOrderPaymentPage({
    Key? key,
    required this.addressID,
    required this.totalAmount,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String addressID;
  final double totalAmount;

  @override
  _PlaceOrderPaymentPageState createState() => _PlaceOrderPaymentPageState();
}

class _PlaceOrderPaymentPageState extends State<PlaceOrderPaymentPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AdaptiveLayoutScaffold(
      appBar: const PlaceOrderPaymentPageAppBar(),
      landscapeBodyWidget: Container(),
      portraitBodyWidget: PlaceOrderPageContainer(
        orderOnPressed: () => addOrderDetails(),
      ),
    );
  }

  void addOrderDetails() {
    final time = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;

    writeOrderDetailsForUser({
      ShoppingApp.addressID: widget.addressID,
      ShoppingApp.totalAmount: widget.totalAmount,
      'orderBy': ShoppingApp.sharedPreferences.getString(
        ShoppingApp.userUID,
      ),
      ShoppingApp.productID: ShoppingApp.sharedPreferences.getStringList(
        ShoppingApp.userCartList,
      ),
      ShoppingApp.paymentDetails: ShoppingPageString.cashOnDelivery,
      ShoppingApp.orderTime: time.toString(),
      ShoppingApp.isSuccess: true,
    });

    writeOrderDetailsForAdmin({
      ShoppingApp.addressID: widget.addressID,
      ShoppingApp.totalAmount: widget.totalAmount,
      'orderBy': ShoppingApp.sharedPreferences.getString(
        ShoppingApp.userUID,
      ),
      ShoppingApp.productID: ShoppingApp.sharedPreferences.getStringList(
        ShoppingApp.userCartList,
      ),
      ShoppingApp.paymentDetails: ShoppingPageString.cashOnDelivery,
      ShoppingApp.orderTime: time.toString(),
      ShoppingApp.isSuccess: true,
    }).whenComplete(() => {
          emptyCartNow(),
        });
  }

  void emptyCartNow() {
    ShoppingApp.sharedPreferences.setStringList(ShoppingApp.userCartList, [
      'garbageValue',
    ]);
    List<String>? tempList = ShoppingApp.sharedPreferences.getStringList(
      ShoppingApp.userCartList,
    );

    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc(ShoppingApp.sharedPreferences.getString(
          ShoppingApp.userUID,
        ))
        .update({
      ShoppingApp.userCartList: tempList,
    }).then((value) {
      ShoppingApp.sharedPreferences.setStringList(
        ShoppingApp.userCartList,
        tempList as List<String>,
      );
      Provider.of<CartItemCounterProvider>(
        context,
        listen: false,
      ).displayResult();
    });
    Fluttertoast.showToast(
      msg: ToastString.orderPlacedSuccessfully,
    );
    Navigator.pushReplacement(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => const ShoppingPage(),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> writeOrderDetailsForUser(
    Map<String, dynamic> data,
  ) async {
    await ShoppingApp.firestore
        .collection(ShoppingApp.collectionUser)
        .doc(ShoppingApp.sharedPreferences.getString(ShoppingApp.userUID))
        .collection(ShoppingApp.collectionOrders)
        .doc(
          ShoppingApp.sharedPreferences.getString(ShoppingApp.userUID)! +
              data['orderTime'],
        )
        .set(data);
  }

  Future<void> writeOrderDetailsForAdmin(Map<String, dynamic> data) async {
    await ShoppingApp.firestore
        .collection(ShoppingApp.collectionOrders)
        .doc(
          ShoppingApp.sharedPreferences.getString(ShoppingApp.userUID)! +
              data['orderTime'],
        )
        .set(data);
  }
}


class CartItemCounterProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  final int _counter = (ShoppingApp.sharedPreferences
              .getStringList(
                ShoppingApp.userCartList,
              )
              ?.length ??
          0) -
      1;
  int get count => _counter;

  Future<void> displayResult() async {
    
    int _counter = (ShoppingApp.sharedPreferences
                .getStringList(
                  ShoppingApp.userCartList,
                )
                ?.length ??
            0) -
        1;

    await Future.delayed(
        const Duration(
          milliseconds: 100,
        ), () {
      notifyListeners();
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: could you add the code snippet on how you are calling this PaymentPage widget

Comment: @YanniTheDeveloper.  I added more code above which hopefully includes what you are looking for.  Thanks.

Comment: Its clear for me you have a state management problem, I cannot just debug it over code. If you want me to help you over zoom, you can leave me your email here. I have one Q for example after setting => totalAmount = 0; why are you adding it with model.price? => totalAmount = model.price! + totalAmount;

Comment: @YanniTheDeveloper. Thanks for taking the time to review the code and comment.   The answer to your question about setting totalAmount to 0 and adding the price is that the shopping cart has a 'garbage value' by default.  So in the code the goal is to assign a total amount of 0 for the 0 index.  And then I am trying to add the price to the totalAmount when the index is 1 or greater. Having totalAmount = model.price +totalAmount in the 'if' may not make sense, if that is what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CartCheckOutFAB** is first being instantiated with value 0 always since **ShoppingCartPage** state is not being changed.
You could try to move *Consumer2<TotalAmountProvider, CartItemCounterProvider>* as parent of *AdaptiveLayoutScaffold* and instantiate the **CartCheckOutFAB** with **amountProvider.totalAmount**

- If its not working can you provide the CartCheckOutFAB widget class.

Comment: I updated the code above to include the CartCheckOutFAB class.  I will test your changes this afternoon.  I am extremely appreciative of all of your help.

Comment: I replaced the original code with an updated version of the ShoppingCart that includes your suggestion of moving the Consumer.  At the same time I removed the CartCheckOutFAB as a custom widget and moved it inside the Shopping Cart so you could see the code.  I also added the TotalAmount and CartItemCounter providers and the Address Card so you didn't have to guess about different parts of the code.  I'm stumped as to why your suggested change didn't change the behavior.  I must be making errors away from the code that you have seen previously.  Thanks again for the help.

Comment: 1st remove the Consumer in SliverToBoxAdapter, as its duplicate, 2nd use AddressPage(totalAmount: amountProvider.totalAmount,), in the MaterialPageRoute. 3rd Try to to check the value of totalAmount in all Classes with the help of Break point or print to console. or use Provider.of<TotalAmountProvider>(
                                                  context).totalAmount while passing totalAmount to PlaceOrderPaymentPage() in the AddressCardState

Comment: Thanks for the tremendous help.  I will follow your suggestion step by step and let you know how it goes.  I quickly did a print to console and immediately saw that when the FAB is pressed in the Shopping cart the total amount value is 0 so your idea will allow me to pin point where things are going wrong.  This is great!  I obviously didn't think to do this before you suggested it.

Comment: displayResult in the CartItemCountProvider results in 'Instance of 'Future<void>' so as you said in your very first comment I have a State Management issue. It looks like the displayResult method isn't doing anything because the int variable isn't being used.

Comment: You also previously mentioned  totalAmount = model.price! + totalAmount in the Shopping Cart class as a potential issue.  I'm also guessing now based on your comment that I need to provide the number of items in the cart at that point.  I'm new so I can't figure things out quickly but I will work on this in the AM and try to get to the bottom of it. Thanks again.

Comment: Okay great, I am happy it gave you a clue!

Comment: It will probably take me a few days to figure this out as I am still struggling to get things to work but you have done as much as is humanly possible.  I have work to do and then if I cannot resolve it on my own in a few days I will at least be able to post a shorter more specific question with significantly less code thanks to what you have helped me with.  Thanks.